# Delete the dynamically created <li> list item on clicking icon at the end of the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've a `<li`> list that's dynamically created using jquery. The list has an input field and a minus icon to remove the list item. Here's the sample code that inserts a new item to the list:

```
$list = $("#servicesList");
$list.append(""<li data-value='" + uniqueIdentifier + "'>
(same line) <input type='text' class='input-mini' id='price' value='2500'>
(same line) <i id='icon-minus' class='icon-minus-sign'></i></li>
```

This list item is added dynamically to the div servicesList which is a ul item.

```
<ul id="servicesList">
</ul>
```

Now, I need to remove the item when someone clicks the minus icon for a list item. Since the list item is generated dynamically, I'm using the document method to add click event listener. Here's the code that's not working.

```
$(document).on('click','#icon-minus',function() {
    var $list =  $("#servicesList"),
    listValue = $(this).attr("data-value");
    $list.find('li[data-value="' + listValue + '"]').slideUp("fast", function() 
            {
              $(this).remove();
            });
```

The above code is not working. If I pass "#servicesList li" to the on click function, then the code works but then the list item is deleted even on clicking the text input field. I want the list item to be deleted only on clicking the minus icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two problems: if you click on the minus, `$(this)` refers to the `<i>` element, not the parent `<li>` element, so you are not gettin the proper value in `var listValue`.

Second, I think you don't want to use an id for `icon-minus` but a class instead, since there are multiple icon-minuses on the page (id's are unique).

example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/X9nFX/5/

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this code and this is working: http://jsfiddle.net/Vc3zg/

```
$("#servicesList").append('<li><input type="text" value="" /> <span id="icon-minus">X</span></li>');

$(document).on('click', '#icon-minus', function() {
   var $list = $("#servicesList"),
   listValue = $(this).attr("data-value");
   $list.find('li').slideUp("fast", function() {
       $(this).remove();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ID should always be unique (that's why it is called ID). So make sure you change all your ID to class and try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#icon-minus',function() {
  var $list =  $("#servicesList"),
  
  $(this).parent().slideUp("fast", function() 
  {
      $(this).remove();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that all your buttons share the same ID

`ID` MUST be unique-per-page. Use ***class*** instead for your buttons

And fix your quotes inside your `$list.append(`

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you're adding potentially multiple elements, all with the same `icon-minus` `id` attribute. In HTML pages the `id` attribute of each element has to be unique. I would switch to using the class instead:

```
$(document).on('click','.icon-minus-sign',function() {
```

The next issue is that `this` inside the function for the event handler refers to the `<i>` element, so this line:

```
listValue = $(this).attr("data-value");
```

doesn't work; the element referred to by `this` doesn't *have* a `data-value` attribute. You'll need to access the `<li>` that contains the `<i>` element instead:

```
$(this).closest('li').slideUp("fast", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```